# Computing MLE with a linear regression model

Tags: statistics, information-theory, maximum-likelihood, linear-regression

I am stuck on how to compute the MLE for $β$ given the model $y_i = βx_i + \varepsilon_i$. I know that $β$ is an unknown slope, the $x_i$ are deterministic inputs, and the $y_i$ are random
observations. I also know that the $\varepsilon_i$ are random variables, and are independent, mean zero, variance $1$ normal distributions. The indices $i$ range between $1$ and a fixed number $n$.
I know that I have to get a regression formula, but I'm stuck on how to get there.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried?